# How to get iOS device info without asking permission?

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions

With Flutter package device_info_plus I can get device info. But on iOS devices I see permission popup. If user decline the permission , I will not be able to continue my signin functionality.

I tried to find other ways to solve this , but there aren’t working.

Comment: What permission is being requested?  What device information are you requesting?  If young could get the information without permission what would be the point of ios requiring permission?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.